# score not resetting to zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm having problem in the score and high score when i play the game and eat coin its increasing the score and high score but when i die and play again its start counting from the score before i dead like i dead my score was 3 when i play again without closing the game its start counting from 3 and the high score aren't saving

Score Manager script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text hiScoreText;

    public static int scoreCount;
    public int hiScoreCount;

    public bool scoreIncreasing;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))
        {
            hiScoreCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 

        if (scoreIncreasing)
        {
            scoreCount = BallMain.getPoints();
        }

        if (scoreCount > hiScoreCount)
        {
            hiScoreCount = scoreCount;
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", hiScoreCount);
        }

        scoreText.text = "Score: " + (scoreCount);
        hiScoreText.text = "High Score: " + (hiScoreCount);
    }    
}
```

BallMain Script

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public static class BallMain  {

    private static float ballSpeed = 1.2f;
    private static int points;
    private static int lives = 0;

    public enum BallStateEnum { shielded,Vulnerable};

    public static BallStateEnum ballState = BallStateEnum.Vulnerable;

    public static float getBallSpeed()
    {
        return ballSpeed;
    }

    public static void IncreaseSpeed()
    {
        ballSpeed += 0.1f;
    }

    public static void IncreasePoints()
    {
        points++;

    }

   public static int getPoints()
    {
        return points;
    }

    public static int getLive()
    {
        return lives;
    }

    public static void addLife()
    {
        lives++;
    }
}
```

CoinHandler Script

```
  using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class coinHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform particles;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Instantiate(particles, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -0.2f), Quaternion.identity);
            BallMain.IncreaseSpeed();
            BallMain.IncreasePoints();
            GameObject.FindWithTag("CoinUI").GetComponent<Text>().text = BallMain.getPoints().ToString();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

BadCoinHandler Script

```
  using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class BadCoinHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform particles;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject, 8f);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Instantiate(particles, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -0.2f), Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(gameObject);

            if(BallMain.getLive() == 0 && BallMain.ballState == BallMain.BallStateEnum.Vulnerable)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you restarting the scene? Could you please write down the code.

Comment: I write it Its "BadCoinHanlder"

Comment: This is not unityscript please do not tag it if your question only is about c# in unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to zero the score manually. Because you are using the static keyword. So create another void in *BallMain* and make the point zero; Example:

```
public static void ResetPoints()
{
    points = 0;
}
```

And call it on awake method on *Score Manager script*; Example:

```
void Awake()
{
    scoreCount = 0; //Also the score here
    BallMain.ResetPoints(); 
}
```

To save your high score use this:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore",scoreCount);//HighScore is key and scoreCount is the number you want to save
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

BTW I thing you need another void to reset ball speed as well.

Comment: Thanks that's works what about saving high score ? any idea ?

Comment: If this solution worked please click on the check button to make this the answer.

Comment: I will but can u tell me how to save my high score ?